# Unexpected error alert in selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am very new to Selenium and automation. And I also have very basic knowledge in programming languages. I am using Selenium IDE to test my web application. When I playback, test case failed, in a place where we need to click a link which will reload to new page. ( In my UI this is a button with some text).

Below is the selenium log:

```
[info] Executing: |clickAndWait | xpath=html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/a | |

[error] There was an unexpected Alert! []

[info] Test case failed

[info] Test suite completed: 1 played, 1 failed
```

My problem is there was no alert being shown in the web page when I click the link. Could anyone help me in handling this error with selenium IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an unexpected alert box (javascript `alert('foo')`)in the browser window and it's preventing Selenium to move forward.